# How do I combine strings in an if/else statements in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner learning C++, and I'm confused about where I've gone wrong here. So far I have what is below, but it's not recognizing the && operand for this. What would I use in place of &&?

What I'm suppose to be doing is writing a program that prompts the user to enter the names of two primary colors to mix. I'd appreciate any and all advice.

Thank you.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        //Declare string variables for colors to mix

        string color;
        string color2;
        string red;
        string yellow;
        string blue; 

        //Output instructions for creating secondary color
        cout<< " Enter first primary color to help create a secondary color.";
        cout<< " Must be in lowercase letters. "<<endl;

        cin>>color;

        cout<< "Enter another primary color to help create a secondary color: ";
        cout<< " Must be in lowercase letters. "<<endl;
        cin>>color2;


        //Create statements to help determine the results
        if (red && yellow)
        {cout<< " Your secondary color is Orange! ";

        }

        else if (red && blue) 
        {cout<< " Your secondary color is Purple! ";


        }

        else if (blue && yellow) 
        {cout<< " Your secondary color is Green! ";

        }

        else 
        {cout<< "Input is inaccurate. Please enter a different color. ";


        }


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `if (red && yellow)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You never assign any values to `red`, `yellow` and `blue`.

Comment: The content of the strings `red` and `yellow` are not defined nor initialized before they are compared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (red && yellow)
```

`&&` asks if each side evaluates to true, and if so, will itself evaluate to true.

This means your code is asking if the variable `red` evaluates to true and the variable `yellow` evaluates to true.

But those are strings! (and empty ones at that!) Instead, you want to compare the strings that were input and see if the comparisons evaluate true:

```
if (color1 == "red" && color2 == "yellow")
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like

```
if (color == "red" && color2 == "yellow")
```

The names of variables are not strings.

Answer (score 3):

The operator `&&` is valid when both sides of the operator are `bool` objects or objects that can be converted to `bool`. Hence, the line

```
    if (red && yellow)
```

is syntactically incorrect.

Your intent can be correctly expressed in code by using:

```
    if (color == "red" && color2 == "yellow" )
```

If you define the vlaues of the variables `red` and `yellow` as:

```
    string red = "red";
    string yellow = "yellow";
```

then you may also use:

```
    if (color == red && color2 == yellow )
```